# Is it possible to write an AND gate using XOR gates?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

How could I express an AND gate using only XOR gates ?

Comment: why you want to express and gates with xor and in what ?

Comment: I am reading something about homomorphic encryption, namely this paper https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/094.pdf also known as LTV scheme. There it is stated that multiplication means AND, addition between two bits means XOR. So I ask if it is possible to rewrite the scheme using only XOR ? Maybe I should migrate the question to Cryptography beta?

Comment: Related: [Functional completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106934/logic-gates-realize-or-gate-using-only-xor-gates/

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/140684/construct-an-and-gate-from-xor-gates

Answer (score 37):

You cant.

Since $XOR$ is associative, i.e. $(x_1\oplus x_2)\oplus x_3=x_1\oplus(x_2\oplus x_3)$, you can only implement functions of the form $x_{i_1}\oplus...\oplus x_{i_k}$ where $x_{i_j}\in\{x_1,x_2\}$. This is equivalent to (depending on the parity of the number of instances of $x_1$ and $x_2$) either 0, $x_1$, $x_2$, or $x_1\oplus x_2$, which are not equivalent to AND.

Comment: You might want to allow 0 and 1 as inputs as well.  You still will not get AND though, although you will get the negation of the above as well.

Answer (score 19):

Hmmm. It can't be done with boolean algebra that's for sure, but I could wire one up physically. The trick is wiring one of the inputs to a power lead of an XOR gate.

```
                     I2
                     |
      0  I1          |
      |   |          |
     \|   |/         |
     |\   / |        |
.|---| \ /  |--------/
     \  V  /  
      \   /  
       \ /  
        V 
        |            
     AND OUTPUT
```

The XOR gate is wired up as a non inverting buffer. The trick involved is that if you wire VCC to GND (or by extension a logic ground), the output is a weak GND.

Disclaimer: this works on the silicon I have, but might not work on all silicon.

Comment: Some explanation of how this works would make this a much better answer.

Comment: Isn't the first gate redundant in this case?

Comment: What are these `.|`, `|>`?

Comment: @Wojowu ground and Vcc, I presume.

Comment: "might not work on all silicon." ... yes, and might even damage some - applying an input to a physical gate with the power turned off, or even worse turning the power on afterwards, is out-of-spec for a lot of parts (re: CMOS latchup effect!). Also, the "true" output voltage of the first gate is lower than your supply voltage, and depending on how much lower it is, will shift interpretation of input levels at the second gate significantly. And it is not unlikely (protection diodes, complimentary output...) that I2 will be an effective short circuit to ground when lower gate is unpowered.

Comment: @rackandboneman: On my silicon, this does not short to ground no matter the input. You do raise a good point, though. While this solution works, it does not stack; the label "AND OUTPUT" can't be connected to a power pin because the next diode voltage drop pushes it below the activation minimums.

Comment: Most (SSI/MSI) Logic families will have a diode towards VCC from the input, and the output circuit of almost any implementation would tie the VCC of the gate supplied straight to ground -> short that will give a puzzling surprise if the output of the supplying gate is used for anything else. The actual diode drop would only be true with bipolar logic though, but CMOS will suffer similarly after a few stacking iterations. Also, there is no VCC bypass/filter with that solution, and that can yield very interesting side effects...

Comment: Figures. I always paid extra for diode-protected hardware to avoid burning up my chips from miswiring.

Answer (score 2):

No

Consider W the set of the functions that maps {0, 1}×{0, 1} to {0, 1}. For example, the AND gate (denoted by ^) and the XOR gate (denoted by ⊕) are elements of W.

Now, for f ∈ W, define Val(f) in that way:

Val(f) := f(0, 0) ⊕ f(0, 1) ⊕ f(1, 0) ⊕ f(1, 1)

Its possible to prove that Val(¬f) = Val(f) and that Val(f ⊕ g) = Val(f) ⊕ Val(g). Now, let A(x, y) = x and B(x, y) = y two of the elements of W, and note that Val(A) = Val(B) = 0, and that Val(^) = 1

To finish, suppose that ^ can be expressed using only A, B, ⊕ and negations, so we have something like

A ^ B = ¬((¬A) ⊕ ((¬B) ⊕ A)) ⊕ ... ⊕ ((¬A) ⊕ (¬(A ⊕ ¬(A ⊕ B))))

and applying Val in both sides, we have

Val(A ^ B) = Val(¬((¬A) ⊕ ((¬B) ⊕ A)) ⊕ ... ⊕ ((¬A) ⊕ (¬(A ⊕ ¬(A ⊕ B)))))

→

1 = ((Val(A)) ⊕ ((Val(B)) ⊕ Val(A))) ⊕ ... ⊕ (((Val(A))) ⊕ ((Val(A) ⊕ (Val(A) ⊕ Val(B)))))

→

1 = ((0) ⊕ ((0) ⊕ 0)) ⊕ ... ⊕ (((0)) ⊕ ((0 ⊕ (0 ⊕ 0))))

→

1 = 0

a contradiction.